# Ordering records by an association presence

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Lets say I have an `instructions` table which is associated to a `surveys` table through `survey_instructions` join table.

What I need to achieve is to fetch all instruction records, but ordered by an association presence with a given survey.

So instructions associated with a given survey will go first, and then all other instructions which have no association with this survey.

```
class Instruction < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :survey_instructions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :surveys, through: :survey_instructions
and
```

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :survey_instructions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :instructions, through: :survey_instructions
and
```

```
class SurveyInstruction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :instruction
and
```

Could this be achieved by chaining active record queries somehow? Would appreciate any thoughts on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by `ActiveRecord` query. Try this:

```
survay_id = 10
@instructions = Instruction.includes(:survey_instructions).order("(CASE WHEN survey_instructions.survay_id = #{survay_id} THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ASC NULLS LAST")
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately, because it just puts last all instructions which have no surveys at all. But what I need is to use a given survey id, to get first - all associated instructions for the given survey, and then all instructions which have no association with this survey. They might have any association with other surveys

Comment: @A.Chile I have edited the answer. Hope this one will help you.

Comment: Just tried it and it produces `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "survey_instructions"` :(

Comment: On your rails console, run `SurveyInstruction.last` and share the logs here.

Comment: `SurveyInstruction Load (9.3ms)  SELECT  "survey_instructions".* FROM "survey_instructions" ORDER BY "survey_instructions"."id" DESC LIMIT $1 [["LIMIT", 1]]`

Comment: Solved by adding `.references(:survey_instructions)` at the end of your query. Thanks, now works like a charm!